# Draw differents latitude and longitude using thymeleaf and google maps

Tags: javascript, html, spring, maps, thymeleaf

I am getting multiples latitude and longitude and I am trying to draw in Google Maps, but I don't know exactly how to do it, I think my problem is in the HTML.

Here is my Java Code using Spring:

``

```
@RequestMapping("/mapausuarios") //controlador que controla lo que viene a la raíz
public String mapausers(Model model) throws ParseException {

        tablausuario tu = new tablausuario();
        ArrayList<usuario> user = tu.listausuarios();
        Collections.sort(user, (o1, o2) -> o2.getCreatedAt().compareTo(o1.getCreatedAt())); //tabla ordenada
        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", user);

    return "mapausers";

}
```

I can extract de latitudes and longitudes in a table using that:

```
                    <tbody  th:each="usuariosTotales: ${TodosLosUsuarios}" >
                        <tr>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getLatitude()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getLongitude()} " ></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

But I don't know how can I loop and draw into my script:

```
       <div id="map"></div>
       var geocoder;
       var map;

       <script>
           // Initialize and add the map
           function initMap() {
               // The location of Uluru
               var uluru = {lat: 40.416775, lng: -3.703790};
               // The map, centered at Uluru
               var map = new google.maps.Map(
                       document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
               // The marker, positioned at Uluru
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
           }
       </script>
       <script async defer
               src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***********&callback=initMap">
       </script>
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  var user = ${TodosLosUsuarios} ;

   function plotUser(user) {
       // The location of Uluru
       var uluru = {lat: user.latitude, lng: user.longitude};
       // The map, centered at Uluru
       var map = new google.maps.Map(
               document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
       // The marker, positioned at Uluru
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
   }

  function loadUsers()
   {
        var user = ${TodosLosUsuarios} ;
        for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
        {
            plotUser(users[i]);
        }           
   }
```

```
<script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***********&callback=loadUsers">
```

In order to plot users you need to store your users data on front end here is one of the solution. I hope it work for you

Comment: Is not working, I guess cause "user.lat" is not defined, I tried to do it using  -->  var uluru = {lat: user.getLatitude(), lng: user.getLongitude()}; but it doesn't work either :/

Comment: I have updated it should user.longitude and user.latitude I forgot to check variable name.